# How to Bi-directional link two nodes from different content type?

Tags: 7, nodes, navigation

Hello i am new to Drupal. I have used Joomla for very long time and some wordpress.

I want to link 2 or more nodes bi-directional. Meaning that if i link A to B, B must be also linked to A.

I will give you a simple example:

Lets say i want to make a Lyrics site. Where i will have 2 content types.

- 1) Artist / Band
- 2) Song Lyrics

The **Artist / Band** type will have information about the artist with maybe a photo and textaera for description.

The **Song Lyrics** will have the actual song lyrics (textaera).

Finally i want to link the Song Lyrics to an Artist / Band. So when i view the Lyrics page it will link to the Artist page. And when i go to the artist page it will link to all the lyrics that are available for that artist.

How can i do this in **Drupal 7**? Can i do it with the Core, or do i need to install additional Modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also check out these modules (quotes included are from their project pages):

- [References Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/references):

  > ... provides D7 versions of the 'node_reference' and 'user_reference' field types, that were part of the CCK package in D6, at functional parity with the D6 counterparts.
- [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference):

  > Provides a field type that can reference arbitrary entities:
  >
  > - A generic entity reference field
  > - Four widgets:
  >
  >   - Two implemented on top of the Options module (Select and Radios/Checkboxes),
  >   - Two autocomplete widgets (one with one text field per entry, one tag-style with comma-separated entries in the same text field)
  > - Two formatters:
  >
  >   - A "Label" formatter, with optional link that displays the label of the referenced entity (the node title, the user name, etc.)
  >   - A "Rendered entity" formatter, that renders the references entity using a configurable view mode
  > - Integration with Views (for both forward and backward references)
  > - Integration with Entity Metadata (and as a consequence with Search API and the like)
  > - Integration with Devel generate
  > - Integration with Feeds and Migrate (>= 2.3) for painless data import
- [EVA: Entity Views Attachment](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva)

  > ... provides a Views display plugin that allows the output of a View to be attached to the content of any Drupal entity. The body of a node or comment, the profile of a user account, or the listing page for a Taxonomy term are all examples of entity content.

Comment: Can you explain a little what solution you chose and how you implemented it in order to make your answer more explicit ?

Comment: For my current needs i choosed the "Artist" to be taxonomy. Drupal 7 core taxonomy custom fields helped me to add description and artist photo.

Answer (score 3):

While still new and with rough edges, the [Relation module](http://drupal.org/project/relation) will be the right module for that job.